# how to get b43 wifi to work reliably on MacBookPro8,2?

Tags: wireless, mac, macbook-pro

I have a MacBookPro8,2 (15-inch, Early 2011) and have installed Ubuntu using wubi on the windows partition. I could never get the b43 wifi chip to work reliably and I ended up buying a belkin usb wifi F9L1001v1 which has a realtek chip with r8712u module. Life is way better but still connecting to wifi hotspot is so random and fail many times. It works at home.

I have no idea why and do not have the skills to debug it. ro

1> Why the dongle work at home by have trouble connecting to some hotspots?

2> Has anybody been able to get the b43 work RELIABLY on this mac? Here is the lspci output

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00d6]
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
Memory at b0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 27-b8-8f-ff-ff-08-e4-ce
Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
Kernel modules: bcma
```

Here is the kernel info

```
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-44-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:01:04 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the instruction that I have followed.

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

3> I want to get a new laptop/mac but I hate the fact that I also need a dongle to use my Mac and with this horrible wifi experience makes me wonder if I should ignore apple if I want to use ubuntu only?

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers and also note the "IMPORTANT NOTE" note section, in case it applies to your hardware.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I was never able to get it to work reliably, though on my MacBook Air 6,2 wifi works like a charm (different chipset tho): http://askubuntu.com/questions/524402/itermittent-loss-of-wireless-14-04-dual-boot-on-mac/524465#524465